# Error opening shapefile located on network

Tags: shapefile, gdal, c#

I have been able to successfully open a shapefile using Gdal when it is situated on my local machine. However, when I put the file on another machine on the network and try to open it, it fails.

There is no exception thrown which I can read through and explore. The operation simply returns null. Below is the code that I have used for both cases.

```
private const String LocalShapeFilePath = @"C:\FakePath\VectorData.shp"
private const String NetworkShapeFilePath = @"\\NetworkServer\FakePath\VectorData.shp"

//The line below works fine and dataLocal is not null
var dataLocal = Ogr.Open(LocalShapeFilePath, (int)Access.GA_ReadOnly);

//The line below fails to open the data source and dataNetwork is null
var dataNetwork = Ogr.Open(NetworkShapeFilePath, (int)Access.GA_ReadOnly);
```

Just to make an another attempt, instead of opening the file using `Ogr.Open()`, since I know that it is shapefile, I used `drv.Open()` with `drv = Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");`. The output is still the same. Local file opens while network based file is null.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual remote path was like:

```
private const String NetworkShapeFilePath = @"\\NetworkServer\FakePath\_vectordata.shp"
```

and I had it written like:

```
private const String NetworkShapeFilePath = @"\\NetworkServer\FakePath\vector_data.shp"
```